# Postgresql not working with django on Macos: El Capitan

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I installed Postgresql from the official site (version 4.0), I created a database with "pgAdmin 4", and tried to connect my django project to it.

But an error prevented me from the running the django server, the error says:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/yyy/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-G0YpajmP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
```

---

The django project is created inside a "pipenv" virtual environment with the following pip packages installed:

```
asgiref            3.4.1
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.7
cPython            0.0.6
Django             3.1.13
idna               3.3
pip                21.2.4
postgres           4.0
psycopg2-binary    2.9.1
psycopg2-pool      1.1
pymongo            3.12.1
pytz               2021.3
requests           2.26.0
setuptools         58.2.0
sqlparse           0.4.2
urllib3            1.26.7
wheel              0.37.0
```

I tried other solutions but all of them didn't work.

Why doesn't postgresql run probably with django on my machine?

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I think I have seen people complaining online that they have had problems installing psycopg2-binary on recent Macs. The error is saying that psycopg2 couldn't be loaded.

Comment: @RichardHuxton thank you for the reply. I am frustrated with this error because I downloaded postgresql with no problems on UBUNTU 18 both locally and on a remote server ! so I assumed the process will go smoothly on MAC also.

Comment: It's not a problem with postgresql - it's the python libraries for your django project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem by downloading [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html)**

and xcode for OS X EL CAPITAN 10.11.6 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Anaconda has psycopg2 and downloads it without any problems.
Now I have a conda virtual environment with Django + postgresql installed, working perfectly with EL CAPITAN 10.11.6.

Thumbs up for @RichardHuxton comment: the problem was the django project virtual environment.